# Problem with operator+ of templated inherited class

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure a problem with a piece of code that I wrote.

I have two `struct`s (`bar` and `foo`) that can be used to contruct a templated class `myClass`.
For this example, the `struct`s will contain information about the size of a vector of a templated quantity (called `baseType`).

There is also a third `struct` called `infoClass` which will contain some information about the object, e.g., its `name`.

The class `myClass` will inherite from `infoClass` and from either `bar` or `foo`.

When I write the `operator+` for `myClass`, the compiler is allowing me to do:
`myClass<double, foo>  = myClass<double, bar> + myClass<double, bar>;`

I was able to track the problem to the constructor `myClass (const infoClass& obj)`.

If I put an extra parameter I will get the error I am expecting saying:
`error: conversion from ‘myClass<[...],bar>’ to non-scalar type ‘myClass<[...],foo>’ requested`

However, I am not understanding why do I need to put an extra parameter in the constructor for the code to work as expected.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct bar
{
    int size{10};
};

struct foo
{
    int size{15};
};

struct infoClass
{
    std::string name;
};

template<typename baseType, typename myType>
class myClass;


typedef myClass<double, bar> doubleBar;
typedef myClass<double, foo> doubleFoo;

template<typename baseType, typename myType>
class myClass
:
public infoClass,
public myType
{
    private:
    std::vector<baseType> data_;

    public:
        myClass(double initValue) : data_(this->size,{initValue}){}

        myClass (const infoClass& obj) // myClass (const infoClass& obj, double someVar) //this works
        : 
        data_(this->size,{0})
        {
            this->name = obj.name;
        }

        std::vector<baseType>& data() {return data_;}
        const std::vector<baseType>& data() const {return data_;}
};


template<typename baseType, typename myType>
myClass<baseType, myType> operator+(const myClass<baseType, myType>& obj1, const myClass<baseType, myType>& obj2)
{
    if(obj1.data().size() != obj2.data().size())
        std::cout << "error, sizes are different" << std::endl;
    
    myClass<baseType, myType> result(0);

    for(int i=0; i < obj1.data().size(); i++)
    {
        result.data()[i] = obj1.data()[i] + obj2.data()[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main() 
{

    doubleBar a(3);
    doubleBar b(4);

    doubleBar c = a + b;

    doubleFoo e = a + a;

    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you put in the "extra parameter", where, exactly, do you expect this extra parameter to come from?

Comment: Unrelated: `std::vector<baseType>& data() {return data_;}` just shattered encapsulation. Now any fool can completely <expletive deleted> an instance of this class and it can't defend itself. Prefer to write functions that operate on a class over functions that hand off the classes data for other classes to operate on.

Comment: Futurebug: `myClass<baseType, myType> result(0);` looks like it makes a `myClass` with a `vector` of size zero. `result.data()[i] = obj1.data()[i] + obj2.data()[i];` will write out of bounds of the size-zero `vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is indeed in `myClass (const infoClass& obj)` constructor. Such constructor is called "converting construcor" and can be used by compiler to implicitly convert one type to another.

Since both of you types `doubleBar` and `doubleFoo` can be implicitly converted to `infoClass` comlpiler then can convert it back to either of these classes. To prevent this implicit behavior just add keyword `explicit` in this constructor declaration, i.e.:

```
explicit myClass (const infoClass& obj)
```

This will tell compiler not to use this constructor for implicit conversion and everything will work as you expect.